# How to start with this equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

What first few lines of the solution are?

\begin{equation}
y'=\frac{\sin x + e^x (\sin x + \cos x) + x\cos x - y(1 + \cos x + e^x)}{e^x + \sin x + x - 2y}
\end{equation}

My trial: I tried to separate the fraction and tried to integrate it. But I got stuck.

which curve then goes thru point (0,0) ?

Answer (score 3):

One could begin the following way, by multiplying by the denominator and moving the $y$ term to the left-hand side:
$$
y'(e^x + \sin(x) + x -2y) + y(1+\cos(x) + e^x) = \sin(x) + e^x(\sin(x) + \cos(x)) + x\cos(x)
$$
and note that if we set $z = y(e^x + \sin(x) + x - y)$, then the left-hand side is simply $z'$. (You see it more clearly if you move one of the two $y$ from the left parenthesis into the right parenthesis, making it $-y'$.) That means we've reduced the equation to
$$
z' = \sin(x) + e^x(\sin(x) + \cos(x)) + x\cos(x)\\
= \sin(x) + x\cos(x) + e^x \sin(x) + e^x\cos(x)\\
= [x\sin(x) + e^x\sin(x)]'
$$
which is more readily solved.

Comment: I have problems after this step.

Comment: @monday25 We have established that $$y(e^x + \sin(x) + x - y) = x\sin(x) + e^x\sin(x) + C$$by solving the (now very easy) differential equation at the end of my answer, and inserting for $z$ again. If you multiply out the parentheses and arrange everything, you get
$$
ye^x + y\sin(x) + yx - y^2- x\sin(x) - e^x\sin(x) - C = 0\\
y^2 - (e^x  + \sin(x) + x)y + x\sin(x) + e^x\sin(x) + C = 0
$$and we can use the quadratic formula, giving
$$
y = \frac12(e^x + \sin(x) + x) \pm \frac12\sqrt{(e^x + \sin(x) + x)^2 -4(x\sin(x) + e^x \sin(x) + C)}
$$which means we have two families of solutions.

Comment: This now completes my understanding. OK

Comment: which then goes thru point (0,0) ?

Comment: @monday25 You figure that out by calculating $y(0)$ and finding the value of $\pm$ and of $C$ that makes it into $0$ (there is only one, as there should be).

Comment: I calculated C=0;  THE result equation I got is as follows.                    : $$ y = 0.5(e^x + sin(x) + x) +0.5*sqrt{(e^x + sin(x) + x)^2 -4(x\sin(x) + e^x sin(x) )$$}

Comment: @monday25 That is correct, but don't forget that you need to pick $-$ as the sign in front of the square root.